# AS3 FDT How to instantiate an fla asset with a custom class?

Tags: flash-builder, flash-cs5, fdt, actionscript-3

I jsut started working at a company that uses flash builder, but I am using fdt at the moment. I am hvaing trouble getting FDT to instantiate the sprite in an fla project along with the custom class that goes with it.

Also, for some reasont he people here say instantiating a sprite like this is WRONG:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MoviClip()
```

and this is right:

```
var _someClass:Class = getDfinitionByName("Linkage") as Class;
var _mc:Sprite = new _someClass() as Sprite
```

I cannot figure out how to instantiate the movieclip in the fla and also the as class at the same time with this method.

Comment: For anyone trying to do this, set the linkage name of the moveiclip in flash IDE to include the package, like this "com.project.Class"

Answer (score 0):

Is the asset a 'Sprite' or a 'MovieClip'? Although you can create Sprite assets in Flash Professional (FLA) it's likely the asset is a Movieclip.

Please confirm this.

Alao, a 'Movieclip' is a 'Sprite' since it inherits from 'Sprite'.

That way of linking is quite verbose and not typical. Are you linking the asset at compile or runtime?

Most people just export assets as a SWC. If you want to get the asset at runtime it's a different thing a bit...

[Look at this post.](http://www.codeandvisual.com/2009/how-to-import-movieclips-into-a-flash-builder-actionscript-project/)

Answer (score 0):

You use getDfinitionByName("Linkage") when your assets are loaded at runtime. If they are linked at compile time (as an swc library) then you're free to do var mc:Linkage = new Linkage(); instead.